# EFS mounting in another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mount, amazon-efs

I have an odd request from management (is there any other kind?) and was hoping to get some info here.

Is there a way to mount an EFS volume from AWS account **A** to a windows EC2 instance in AWS account **B**?

Comment: Actually, [it is possible](https://serverfault.com/a/799213/153161) to cross VPC and even region boundaries with EFS using a bit of creativity -- I use this setup regularly -- but unless you have an NFS 4.1 client for Windows, you can only do this with Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot.

From [Authentication and Access Control for Amazon EFS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/auth-and-access-control.html)

> Cross-account administration – You can use an IAM role in your account
>   to grant another AWS account permissions to administer your account’s
>   Amazon EFS resources. For an example, see Tutorial: Delegate Access
>   Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles in the IAM User Guide. **Note that
>   you can't mount Amazon EFS file systems from across VPCs or accounts**.
>   For more information, see Managing File System Network Accessibility

Answer (score 3):

This is now supported in AWS EFS - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/amazon-efs-now-supports-access-across-accounts-and-vpcs/

Comment: A link to solution is good but provide something useful in your answer